# Oracle Database Trigger- how to get newly updated/added row

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have requirement wherein I need to get the affected row if a row gets updated or added. I have seen many examples wherein we can use :new or :old keywords to get the columns e.g. new.columnName but is there a way to get the complete row. Code snippet is as below. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_134673016571507516045
  AFTER
  INSERT OR UPDATE ON employees 
    FOR EACH ROW
      DECLARE
        content varchar2(4000) := '||:NEW.row||';   
          BEGIN
             ///////
          END;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle insert into returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707220/oracle-insert-into-returning)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to get a complete row in a trigger - you have to explicitly refer to each column separately.